# A Problem Involving The Greatest Common Divisor

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, contest-math, divisibility, recreational-mathematics

I am stuck with a number theory problem which needs the following lemma.

> **Lemma-** Let $x$ and $y$ be to positive integers such that $g.c.d(x,y)=1$,then the we also have $g.c.d(x+y,x^2-xy+y^2)=1$.
>    My question is whether the lemma is true or not and if it is true then I
>    need the proof.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not true.  Take $x=5,y=4$.  $\gcd(x+y,x^2-xy+y^2)=\gcd(9,21)=3$

I found it by subtracting convenient multiples of $x+y$ from the second term.  $\gcd(x+y,x^2-xy+y^2)=\gcd(x+y,-2xy+y^2)=\gcd(x+y,-3xy)$  The constant $3$ suggests that we want to find an $x+y$ which has a factor of $3$.  We could also have used $x=2,y=1$

Comment: but is there another number except 3 or 1 which is a solution to this g.c.d.?

Comment: Not if $\gcd (x,y)=1$

Comment: then I can solve the problem, thanks

Comment: if the g.c.d. of x and y is d then what can I say about the above g.c.d.?

Comment: I think the possible values are d,3d,3d^2,d^2.Am I correct?

Comment: You can also replace $d^2$ by $d$ times some factor of $d$